# Caracteres especiais em negrito apenas no Safari

Tags: css, codificação-de-caracteres, css-font-face, safari

Os caracteres especiais como ã ou ç estão ficando em negrito apenas no Safari versão 13.

O site está com a meta tag utf-8

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Por exemplo:
Escolha as informa**çõ**es... Selecione as opç**õe**s...

Como já citei, isso acontece apenas no Safari, pelo chrome e IE está tudo ok.

Comment: Já deu uma olhadinha nessa pergunta? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440283/special-characters-printed-bold-on-ios

Comment: Bertozalo obrigado pela ajuda, mas se for ver a solução proposta nesse post, o que o cara fez de fato foi trocar a font-family por uma semelhante, vc acha se seria viável fazer um rgex ao invés de trocar a font?

Comment: Acho que não. Acredito que o seu problema esteja em algum atributo de estilização.

Answer (score 1):

boa tarde! Você copiou e colou esse texto de algum lugar ex: Word? Se sim tente reescrever o mesmo, como dito no link ->

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626519/semibold-accented-characters-bug

Acaba sendo um problema com a cópia / colagem do Word - substituí-os por caracteres não-Wordified limpos, e o problema será corrigido.

Você pode também colocar essas referencias no CSS do seu site:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço aos que tentaram me ajudar. Mas eu consegui resolver esse problema fazendo o seguinte. A extensões da fonte que estava sendo utilizada era `woff2`, converti para extensão `woff`e funcionou! Aparentemente o Safari não aceita extensões mais atuais.